# Want to filter the percentage from my output

Tags: regex, perl

I Have a command output like this

mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     54%    /etc/mnttab

I want to catch the values before the % that is from above i need 54 as output , how can i get this ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perldoc is a great resource. Check out [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) (tutorial) and [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (all the details). Module [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aDebugger) is also great for visualizing how the matches are happening.

Here's one possible implementation, based on the scant details you provided.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings;
my $data = 'mnttab 0K 0K 0K 54% /etc/mnttab';
my ( $percent ) = $data =~ /(\d+)%/;
say $percent;
```